# Filter rows by count of two column values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

In SQL Server, I have the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE x
(
    ColumnA CHAR NOT NULL
  , ColumnB CHAR NOT NULL
  , ColumnC INT NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT CompositeKey PRIMARY KEY (ColumnA, ColumnB)
);
```

With the following data:

```
INSERT INTO x
VALUES
 ('A', 'X', 2)
,('A', 'Y', 1)
,('B', 'X', 4)
,('B', 'Z', 2)
,('C', 'X', 9)
,('C', 'Y', 3)
,('C', 'P', 2)
,('D', 'X', 6)
,('D', 'Y', 4)
,('E', 'P', 2)
```

I am writing a query with the following 2 predicates:

1. `Count(ColumnA) > 1`
2. `Count(ColumnB) > 2`

**MY QUERY**

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ColumnA]) AS columnA_cnt
          ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ColumnB]) AS columnB_cnt
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
WHERE columnA_cnt >= 2
  AND columnB_cnt >= 3
```

**EXPECTED RESULT**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 2 |
| A | Y | 1 |
| C | X | 9 |
| C | Y | 3 |
| D | X | 6 |
| D | Y | 4 |

**ACTUAL RESULT**

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | X | 2 |
| A | Y | 1 |
| B | X | 4 |
| C | X | 9 |
| C | Y | 3 |
| D | X | 6 |
| D | Y | 4 |

Comment: Your query does not return your expected results. Please clarify.

Comment: Doesn't (B, X, 4) also satisfy all your conditions? I mean, we have 2 Bs (columnA) and 4 Xs (columnB)

Comment: What qaziqarta says is true. You made a mistake when thinking up the sample data it seems. Although you confused the two counts in your query, its result still happens to be correct for your sample data. But the result you show as expected doesn't match your requirements.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner


(B, X, 4) doesn't satisfy my condition and the reason is that I am expecting a final result set where the records must satisfy the below condition.
`Count(ColumnA) > 1` and 
`Count(ColumnB) > 2.`


'B' in 'ColumnA' has repeated only once if I use `Count  Over Partition By`. So I am looking for any other query that help me to have the result that satisfies the conditions

Comment: I think you are confusing things. There are two rows with `ColumnA = 'B'` in the table. If you only look at the rows for `ColumnB = 'X'`you'll find just one row with `ColumnA = 'B'`. But as `(ColoumnA, ColoumnB)` is the primary key, this applies to all criteria. For instance, there are two rows with `ColumnA = 'A'` in the table. If you only look at the rows for `ColumnB = 'X'`you'll find just one row with `ColumnA = 'A'`. This means either (B, X, 4) matches your conditions or no row at all matches them.

Answer (score 0):

`(ColumnA, ColumnB)` is the primary key. Hence

```
COUNT([ColumnA]) OVER (PARTITION BY [ColumnB]) AS columnA_cnt
```

is the same as

```
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ColumnB]) AS columnA_cnt
```

You look at a row's `ColumnB` and count how many times it occurs in the table. So a better name than `columnA_cnt` would probably be `columnB_cnt` ;-)

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *
          ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ColumnA]) AS columnA_cnt
          ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [ColumnB]) AS columnB_cnt
    FROM @DataSource
) DS
WHERE columnA_cnt >= 2
  AND columnB_cnt >= 3
```

Comment: As said earlier, this query gives me unwanted records `(B, X, 4)` in the result with 'B' repeated only once in `Column-A`

Comment: With your query you can easily get wrong results, because you confused `columnA_cnt` and `columnB_cnt`. My query does give you the correct counts and also the results for the criteria you describe in your request. It doesn't match the sample result you are showing, however, because your expected result doesn't match your problem description. Think it through; I suppose you are mistaken abot the expected result.

Comment: I feel sorry for my mistake. As you said that the counter column names(columnA_cnt , columnB_cnt )need to be rearranged, I have done that and updated the post.

However the `Count over partion By` will not give the expected results because of `(B, X, 4)` in the result where value `B`is repeated only once in the resultant set.

With that said, any query that helps me to get the expected result?

Comment: I see now from your answers to the other guys that you are actually looking for a recursive process. Find all rows with Count(ColumnA) > 1 and Count(ColumnB) > 2, then from the result set find again all rows with Count(ColumnA) > 1 and Count(ColumnB) > 2, and so on until there are no more rows to remove. This requires a recursive CTE and is probably difficult to build, as the criteria is on window functions. I am sorry to say that I don't have the time to help you with this, though. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This query meet the requirement with your expected result

```
CREATE TABLE x
(
    ColumnA CHAR NOT NULL
  , ColumnB CHAR NOT NULL
  , ColumnC INT NOT NULL
  , CONSTRAINT CompositeKey PRIMARY KEY (ColumnA, ColumnB)
);

INSERT INTO x
VALUES
 ('A', 'X', 2)
,('A', 'Y', 1)
,('B', 'X', 4)
,('B', 'Z', 2)
,('C', 'X', 9)
,('C', 'Y', 3)
,('C', 'P', 2)
,('D', 'X', 6)
,('D', 'Y', 4)
,('E', 'P', 2)

with cte as (
select * from x
where ColumnA in (select ColumnA from x group by ColumnA having count(ColumnA) >1)
and ColumnB in (select ColumnB from x group by ColumnB having count(ColumnA) >2)
)
select * from cte
where ColumnA in (select ColumnA from cte group by ColumnA having count(ColumnA) >1)
and ColumnB in (select ColumnB from cte group by ColumnB having count(ColumnA) >2)
```

Comment: What is `#test` that you are referring to

Comment: thanks for correction. It was temporary table before i change to cte

Comment: This query(recurssing twice the cte  for filtering the data) may work for this data set but not for conditions like `>=100` However with this approach, one need to have a code with  number of recurrsive filterations if there is large data set and the conditions `Count(ColumnA) > 10`
and `Count(ColumnB) > 100` to get satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you (with a second condition `columnA > 1`, `columnB > 2`) ?:

```
select 
  ColumnA
  ,ColumnB
  ,ColumnC
from (
  select 
    ColumnA
    ,ColumnB
    ,ColumnC
    ,COUNT(ColumnA) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA) AS columnA_cnt
    ,COUNT(ColumnB) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnB) AS columnB_cnt
  from (
      SELECT *
            ,COUNT(ColumnA) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnA) AS columnA_cnt
            ,COUNT(ColumnB) OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnB) AS columnB_cnt
      FROM x
  ) ds where columnA_cnt >= 2 and columnB_cnt >= 3
) ds2 where columnA_cnt > 1 and columnB_cnt > 2
order by columnA, columnB;
```

Comment: This is more similar to the query given by @Bagus.

So this query filters the data twice and may work for this data set but not for conditions like `>=100` However, the query might fail, if there is large data set and the conditions `Count(ColumnA) > 10 and Count(ColumnB) > 100` exists

Comment: @Sarath, can you edit your question? As it is right now, it's not clear what exactly is required, and what does ">=100" and "Count(ColumnA) > 10 and Count(ColumnB) > 100" mean, since it's not mentioned anywhere in the question description.